# Combining 2 columns in sql query based on alternate field

Tags: python, sql, database

I have 2 columns in a database(sent_time, accept_time) which each include time stamps, as well as a field that can have 2 different values (ref_col). I would like to find a way in my query to make a new column (result_col), which will check the value of ref_col, and copy sent_time if the value is 1, and copy accept_time if the value is 2.

I am using pandas to query the database in python, if that has any bearing on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `case` expression   <del>statement</del>  :

```
SELECT sent_time,
       accept_time,
       ref_col,
       CASE WHEN ref_col = 1 THEN sent_col
            ELSE accept_col
        END AS result_col
  FROM Your_Table
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm beginner level with SQL so a case statement wasn't in my knowledge yet.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "I have 2 columns in a *database*", what you actually mean is that you have 2 columns in a **table**, right?

In sql for postgresql it would be something like:

```
select (case when ref_col = 1 then sent_time else accept_time end) as result_col
from mytable
```

don't know how close from SQL standard that is, but would assume it's not that far.

Comment: Yes I meant table, I am checking this solution now but it seems to be working